# How to assert that placeholder text disappears in Flutter widget test?

Tags: flutter, flutter-test

Say I want to assert that when I enter text into a search bar widget, the placeholder text disappears.  This is really just testing the Flutter framework, but it's the first widget test I tried just to understand how to do widget testing and it's concerning that it doesn't just work.

Take the following SearchBar widget under test:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

const BorderRadius _kBorderRadius = BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(32.0));
const Color _kBorderColor = Color(0xFF33BFCC);

class SearchBar extends StatelessWidget {
  SearchBar({this.onClose, this.onChanged});

  final Function onClose;
  final Function onChanged;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return TextField(
      onChanged: onChanged,
      decoration: InputDecoration(
        suffixIcon: IconButton(
          icon: Icon(Icons.close),
          onPressed: onClose,
        ),
        fillColor: Colors.white,
        filled: true,
        hintText: 'Search',
        contentPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10.0, horizontal: 20.0),
        border: OutlineInputBorder(
          borderRadius: _kBorderRadius,
        ),
        enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
          borderSide: BorderSide(color: _kBorderColor, width: 1.0),
          borderRadius: _kBorderRadius,
        ),
        focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
          borderSide: BorderSide(color: _kBorderColor, width: 2.0),
          borderRadius: _kBorderRadius,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

and the following test of that widget:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_test/flutter_test.dart';
import 'package:my_app/ui_components/search_bar.dart';

void main() {
  testWidgets('entering text removes placeholder text',
      (WidgetTester tester) async {
    await tester.pumpWidget(MaterialApp(home: Scaffold(body: SearchBar())));

    await tester.enterText(find.byType(TextField), 'hi');
    await tester.pumpAndSettle();

    final placeholderFinder = find.text('Search');
    final textFinder = find.text('hi');

    expect(textFinder, findsOneWidget);
    expect(placeholderFinder, findsNothing);
  });
}
```

This test fails, because the 'Search' text is still found.  Looking at [how Flutter tests their own text fields](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/master/packages/flutter/test/material/text_field_test.dart), they appear to be using an opacity trick.  If I try the same trick by replacing

```
expect(placeholderFinder, findsNothing);
```

with

```
expect(getOpacity(tester, placeholderFinder), 0.0);
```

where `getOpacity` is defined as:

```dart
double getOpacity(WidgetTester tester, Finder finder) {
  return tester
      .widget<FadeTransition>(
        find.ancestor(
          of: finder,
          matching: find.byType(FadeTransition),
        ),
      )
      .opacity
      .value;
}
```

I get the following error:

> The following StateError was thrown running a test:
>   Bad state: Too many elements 
>   When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
>   0 Iterable.single (dart:core/iterable.dart:554:24)
>   1 WidgetController.widget (package:flutter_test/src/controller.dart:65:30)

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: The hint text has an animation. Have you tried doing an `await tester.pumpAndSettle()` after typing something in the text field?

Comment: I have, thank you for the suggestion.  I'll update the question with the code that uses that and is failing.

Comment: I've just tested myself. Indeed it won't work because the text is still present (although not painted). But at the same time: does it really matter? What you're testing here is an implementation detail of `TextField`.

Comment: I do agree it is testing the framework - it's just discouraging to find that even the most basic of tests require hacks to properly work, and in this case, for some reason work differently than the tests run on the TextField itself.  As an aside, it seems that this type of testing doesn't provide much value since most any test you can run with the methods provided are really just testing the framework itself.

Comment: Alternatively, you may want to use a golden test. It's basically a screenshot-based test (without needing an emulator)

Answer (score 0):

You can get the widget by `firstWidget` and do the test.

```dart
testWidgets('Test name', (WidgetTester tester) async {
  // preparing widget...

  final finder = find.byType(FadeTransition)
  expect(finder, findsOneWidget);

  //getting Text object
  Text widget = tester.firstWidget(finder);

  // validating properies
  expect(widget.opacity.value, equals(0));
}
```

Comment: Text widget = tester.firstWidget(finder);
should be FadeTransition and not Text right ?